# Google Maps Not Load Full

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, zurb-foundation

**First I want to make clear that the solutions found here have not solved.**

I'm trying to show a modal alert with a simple google maps.
More Google Maps Not Load Full:
[image: Google Maps Not Load Full]

**My .js:**

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 8,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function showModal() {
    $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**I did the tests with:**

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

**And:**

```
$('#map-canvas').gmap().triggerEvent('resize');
```

**Nothing works. Can anyone help? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until modal finish loading by set timeout or use modal callback on complete 
state then you init the map.